'open -a' opens a new instance
In my apple script, I use do shell script to call the command open -a "MyApp". Normally, when the application MyApp is already open, its main window gets focused instead of opening a new instance.
However, on one of my machines the behaviour is different depending on how I opened the first instance:

If I open MyApp using the launchpad, then call open -a "MyApp", a new instance of MyApp is opened.
If I open MyApp using open -a "MyApp", then subsequent calls to open -a "MyApp" focus the main window of the already open instance.

EDIT: After some search, I found two instances of MyApp. One in homebrew (which the launcher does not see for some reason) and one in $HOME/Applications which I copied for the launcher. In particular, when I run
osascript -e 'POSIX path of (path to application "MyApp")'

I get /opt/homebrew/Cellar/myapp-1.0.0/MyApp.app/
When I launch MyApp in the launcher, the application that is opened is the copy in $HOME/Application, while when I call open -a "MyApp", the one in /opt/homebrew gets openned.
So now the questions is, where is path to application "MyApp" getting the path from? How do I deregister such an app?

Out of curiosity, why do you use the shell's open command to launch your app in an applescript? Why not use one of the applescript commands, such as launch or activate? eg tell application "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/myapp-1.0.0/MyApp.app" to activate. You could even run it through osascript if necessary.

@Mockman, I wrote this script a few months ago, but I remember trying different ways to focus the main window of the app (including activate but not launch tbh) and open -a seemed to be the most consistent for me.

So your objective is not to actually open anything but rather to bring your app to the fore. Does it have multiple windows and if so, is it necessary to bring only the single window foreward? Or is just bringing the application foreward sufficient?

Indeed, I just need to focus one of the windows. The app has multiple ones but I change the index of the one I want to focus to be first and that seems to work.

I posted an answer that shows how you might bring the app to the fore without using the open command. It should be a bit quicker since it doesn't require that the shell load.

I found the solution to use lsregister to find the list of applications and unregister the duplicate unwanted entries
alias lsregister=/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister

lsregister -dump | grep path: | grep MyApp

lsregister -u UNWANTED_PATH


So this doesn't address the underlying issue that your answer dealt with but it shows how to get the app you want to the front, by using the process' unix id.
set bundle to "com.apple.ScriptEditor.id.steppo-timer"
set goodPath to "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/myapp-1.0.0/MyApp.app"

tell application "System Events"
    
    set ap to application process "steppo timer"
    
    set bid to (get bundle identifier of ap)
    --> "com.apple.ScriptEditor.id.steppo-timer"
    set appFile to POSIX path of application file of ap
    --> "/Users/home/Library/Scripts/coffee timer.app"
    
    -- confirm correct app instance
    if bid is equal to bundle and appFile is equal to goodPosixPath then
        set uid to unix id of ap
        log uid -- optional
        set frontmost of first process whose unix id is uid to true
    end if
end tell

Basically, it takes the correct (predetermined) information for the app and then compares it with the same for the currently active app. If they match, then it gets the unix id of the currently running app and brings the matching process to the fore. Technically, the 'bundle' part isn't necessary and you can get by with just the 'path'. Note that the posix path in appFile does NOT end with a '/', so remember to remove this from goodPath, otherwise you won't get a match.
I got the idea from this answer on stack overflow and further information from this answer. The second answer shows how you might work with a specific window from the app.
